# Add New (data on picklist) Task Status using Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

This is my apex code:

```
public class SampleController{

    public String inputStatus{get;set;}

    public void saveStatus(){
     Task newStatus = new Task();
        newStatus.status = inputStatus;
        insert newStatus;
    }      
}
```

This is my vf code:

```
Task Status Name: < apex:inputText value="{!inputStatus}"/><br />
< apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveStatus}"/>
```

My question:

What do I need to add or change?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a new task with status as "Done" whenever user executes the method "saveStatus". Are you trying to create new task with all details?. In that case you need to do something like below,

```
public Class taskController{   
 public Task task{get;set;}

     public taskController(){
       task = new Task();
     }   
     public void saveStatus(){
       insert task;
     }  

}
```

In the page you need

```
<apex:inputField value={!task.Status}/>
```

Other mandatory fields also should be added, otherwise it will not let you insert task.

Comment: i will add only a Task Status (picklist)

Comment: There are some mandatory fields, without those it will not let you insert task. You might have to relate the task to some record right? otherwise it will be a standalone one.